# MoveIt: "Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints"

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll try to keep this very concise.
After doing the MoveIt setup assistant wizard for a new robot, I wanted to simulate the MoveIt-Gazebo integration. This repository has all the modifications I needed to make to get it working-ish: https://github.com/dhiegomaga/MoveitArm-Example

*robotic_arm_control.yaml* :

```
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50

arm_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - joint_1
    - joint_2
    - joint_3
    - joint_4
    - joint_5
    - joint_6

  constraints:
    goal_time: 2.5                   # Override default
    stopped_velocity_tolerance: 1.0 # Override default
    joint_1:
      trajectory: 1.0
```

*controllers.yaml* :

```
controller_list:
  - name: arm_position_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3
      - joint_4
      - joint_5
      - joint_6
```

However, it is using "effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController", but I would like to control using position.

But when I change to `type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController`, like it is done [here](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller), I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1597152510.808588978, 48.242000000]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ joint_1 joint_2 joint_3 joint_4 joint_5 joint_6 ]

[ERROR] [1597152510.808635527, 48.242000000]: Known controllers and their joints:
```

How do I change to position control without getting such error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359240/moveit:-%22unable-to-identify-any-set-of-controllers-that-can-actuate-the-specified-joints%22/) by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2020-08-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-11**:\

> But when I change to `type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController`

*where* did you change `type` (ie: in which file)?

You cannot directly load `ros_control` controllers on the MoveIt side.

**Comment by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on 2020-08-11**:
it was on `robotic_arm_control.yaml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was to update the URDF file generated to support position control instead of effort control by Gazebo.

This is described [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/285977/could-not-find-resource-in-hardware_interfaceeffortjointinterface/)

I also installed the position control libraries, although I am not sure that was also necessary:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-joint-*
```

---

Originally posted by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) with karma: 138 on 2020-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3